# Create scope with .where on both collection and grand-parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have three models with grand-parent, parent, child relation: `Organization`, `Category`, `Post`.

I'm trying to create a scope in my `Post` model, using `where` first on the passed collection and then on the grand-parent:

```
scope :ready, -> {
  where("next_setup_at < ?", DateTime.current)
    .joins(category: :organization)
    .where("organizations.active = ?", true)
}
```

But Postgres is throwing me an error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "next_setup_at" is ambiguous
>   LINE 1: ...zations"."id" = "categories"."organization_id" WHERE (next_setup...
>                                                                ^
>
> : SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "posts"."category_id" INNER JOIN "organizations" ON "organizations"."id" = "categories"."organization_id" WHERE (next_setup_at < '2016-03-22 15:57:19.971887') AND (organizations.active = 't')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at your `.where` clauses. The second one does a good job at defining what column to query.

```
where("organizations.active = ?", true)
```

The first one doesn't.

```
where("next_setup_at < ?", DateTime.current)
```

You have to define what table the `next_setup_at` column references to. Leading to

```
where("posts.next_setup_at < ?", DateTime.current)
```

**Further imporvement**

You can easily specify what table to reference in pure ActiveRecord like so:

```
where(posts: {next_setup_at: DateTime.current}, categories: {active: true})
```

Comment: The `where` method uses the table's name, not the relation's name.